# Multiple datatypes within a vertex buffer (openGL)

Tags: python, opengl, buffer, pyglet, vertex

I'm studying openGL and am attempting to write a basic program.  I either misunderstand something, or simply cannot find the answers I'm looking for.

I am trying to add data (of multiple data types) to a vertex buffer.  I don't know if this is bad practice or not.  But I figured it would save a lot of space using int for some of my data instead of floats for everything.

Is it possible to add multiple data types into a single vertex buffer?  If so, how?  Is there a best practice with this?

I know how to define each attribute with `glVertexAttribPoint` but then how did I add the data with `glBufferSubData` ?  Right now, my problem is that `glBufferSubData` requires an array and arrays can only have 1 datatype, I believe.

Comment: *"`glBufferSubData` requires an array and arrays can only have 1 datatype,"* - No. [`glBufferSubData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferSubData.xhtml) does not require an array, but it requires a pointer to  byte buffer. Actually the data type of the _data_ parameter is `void*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sidestepping your actual question:

> But I figured it would save a lot of space using int for some of my data instead of floats for everything.

No, you don't save anything. `sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)` on all platforms you're going to be concerned about.

Anyway, you can mix multiple datatypes perfectly fine inside a buffer object, the key here is the stride parameter for glVertexAttribPointer. This is usually called a "array of structs". The following (C) is perfectly fine:

```
struct foo {
    GLfloat a[2];
    GLbyte b[3];
};

enum { N = 10 };

foo arr[N];

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, N*sizeof(foo), arr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(foo), (void*)offsetof(foo, a));
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_BYTE,  GL_FALSE, sizeof(foo), (void*)offsetof(foo, b));
```

Now here's something important to know about "arrays of structs": They are usually less efficient than "structs of arrays" for two reasons:

- Elements of a structure must be self-aligned; depending on what's inside a structure that requirement may mandate the use of padding bytes, i.e. use more space
- If only a subset of elements in a structure are required, due to the way memory fetches work on GPUs, a lot of the data being loaded is thrown away. On GPUs usually streches of consecutive memory are fetched, which usually caches very well due to the high locality of most graphics operations.

In this appnote by Nvidia they're calling it "streams" instead of "arrays.

https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems2/part-iv-general-purpose-computation-gpus-primer/chapter-33-implementing-efficient

Comment: @httpdigest: The `(void*)` just there to either make a C compiler shut up about the implicit cast (which ironically is invoking UB if you're looking at it in a anal-retentive way), or to make it pass the requirements of a C++ compiler alltogether. If you're going down that road anyway, you could just as well grab the function pointer to it, wrap in in Python FFI and declare the `data` parameter to be an integer that's then passed `uintptr_t` type value.

Comment: @httpdigest: It really depends on the binding. But as I said, one can always use FFI `from ctypes import *; gl_vap = cdll.LoadLibrary("libGL.so" if X11 else "opengl32.dll").glVertexAttribPointer; gl_vap.argtypes = [c_uint32, c_int32, c_int32, c_int32, c_int32, c_size_t]; gl_vap(…, offset)`

Comment: I see.  Yes, if the savings on GPU memory aren't there, then I see no reason not to only use floats.  It simplifies things as well.